# How to lock cells on a sheet that reference unlocked cells on another sheet in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have encountered some odd behavior in Excel and don't know if it's expected or not. I have a workbook that is intended for some non-technical people to enter some data in specific cells and then get a calculated output. I am protecting the sheets and workbook to prevent unwanted changes to anything but the necessary data inputs.

The issue is that after unlocking the specific cells for data input and then locking and protecting all worksheets, the cells that *reference* the unlocked cells are still editable. Even though they are formatted as locked and on a protected sheet, I can freely change them if they reference an unlocked cell.

This seems unintuitive for a "protected" sheet that partially defeats the purpose. Is this activity expected? And does anyone know of a workaround to keep these cells locked? Or has this question already been asked and can someone point me to a solution?

EDIT: I am following the typical process for locking and unlocking certain cells. I am using Office 365, but I received this issue from a colleague using another version (not that I think that's the reason for this issue). I can't replicate it with another file, so I am going to tell him the file may need to be rebuilt to fix the issue. Thanks for the responses.

Comment: Do you mean that, if a formula references an unlocked cell, then its result changes if you change the content of the referenced cell. ex. cells `A1` and `B1` are unlocked, cell `C1` is locked and has the formula `A1 + B1`. if you insert values in `A1` and `B1` (say `1` and `2` then the sum (`3`) will be displayed in `C1`. Locking a cell does not prevent formula calculation, it only prevents users from changing it.

Comment: Works as expected in my version of Excel. The only editable cells are those I've specified as unlocked. I'd suggest editing your question to include A) your version of Excel and maybe B) the process you're following, click-by-click, to protect your sheet (and what behavior you've selected to allow in the protected data), C) some more info about what you're seeing - is it only formula cells that are editable despite protection, or other cells as well? The functionality you describe is not expected, should not require a workaround, and (no offense) leads me to suspect user error.

Comment: Unfortunately that situation is not what the issue is. I do want the locked cell to recalculate, as expected. The problem is that the locked cell (C1) is still editable after locking. Upon further inspection, this may be a weird corruption in this one file. I received it from a colleague after he found the issue, but I can't seem to replicate the problem on any other file I have. Unfortunately, I can't easily share the file in question because it has proprietary info on it, but thanks for the response!

Comment: @MSB your issue can be solved by Locking/Protecting entire Sheet first then make some Cells/Cell editable.